# LuaLaTeX: Numito doesn't print Greek characters in chemformula (chemmacro)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, chemformula, chemgreek

In my migration of my documents from PDFLatex to LuaLatex I came across an odd behaviour of `chemgreek` when used with the font packages `Numito` and `XITS`.

When I set the font format in `chemformula` to `\sffamily` Greek characters aren't printed inside a `\ch{}` enviromnent. Outside that environment they are printed as required. Changing the `sans serif font` to `TeX Gyre Heros` does not show this odd behaviour. Nor does compiling using PDFLatex produce that error.

This is (an extended) MWE showing the behaviour:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\usepackage[charter,cal]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[sans-style=upright]{unicode-math} % automatically loads fontspec package
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia}[
    Scale=1.00,
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt]

\setsansfont{Nunito}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]

\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage[body={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[modules={isotope}]{chemmacros}

\chemsetup{greek=fontspec,formula=chemformula}
%\chemsetup[chemformula]{format={\sffamily}} % <= needs to commented out as this locks the chemformula font setting

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Default selections in preamble}
\setchemformula{format=\sffamily}
In LuaLaTeX \chemdelta{} in \verb*|\ch{}| does not print: \textcolor{red}{\ch{^\chemdelta Hl}} (nor do any Greek characters), but  they are printed in \verb*|\vec{}|: $\vec{\chemmu}$

\subsection*{Nunito}
\fontspec{Nunito}
\setchemformula{format={\sffamily}}
\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}
Selected font in \verb*|chemformula| is \textbf{sans serif font} \\
Selected \verb*|greekmapping| is \textbf{fontspec}: 

In LuaLaTeX \chemdelta{} in \verb*|\ch{}| does not print: \textcolor{red}{\ch{^\chemdelta Hl}} (nor do any Greek characters), but  they are printed in \verb*|\vec{}|: $\vec{\chemmu}$

\selectchemgreekmapping{mathdesign}
\noindent Selected \verb*|greekmapping| is \textbf{mathdesign}: 

In LuaLaTeX \chemdelta{} in \verb*|\ch{}| does print: \textcolor{red}{\ch{^\chemdelta Hl}} (as do all Greek characters) as well as in \verb*|\vec{}|: $\vec{\chemmu}$

\subsection*{GFS Artemisia}
\fontspec{gfsartemisia}
\setchemformula{format={\rmfamily}}
\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}
Selected font in \verb*|chemformula| is \textbf{roman font} \\
Selected \verb*|greekmapping| is \textbf{fontspec}: 

In LuaLaTeX \chemdelta{} in \verb*|\ch{}| does print: \textcolor{red}{\ch{^\chemdelta Hl}} (as do all Greek characters) as well as in \verb*|\vec{}|: $\vec{\chemmu}$

\selectchemgreekmapping{mathdesign}
\noindent Selected \verb*|greekmapping| is \textbf{mathdesign}: 

In LuaLaTeX \chemdelta{} in \verb*|\ch{}| does print: \textcolor{red}{\ch{^\chemdelta Hl}} (as do all Greek characters) as well as in \verb*|\vec{}|: $\vec{\chemmu}$
  
\end{document}
```

The output of the above MWE gives:

[image: Nunito output]

Note the rectangles left of the `Hl` where a `\chemdelta` should be printed. Changing the fontmapping of `chemgreek` to `mathdesign:charter` does print the character where it should be. Changing the `chemformula` font to `rmfamily` does print the `\chemdelta` character using either `fontspec` (XITS) or `mathdesign` mapping.

Changing the default sans serif font in this MWE to `TeX Gyre Heros` also prints the Greek characters in either mapping, as is shown by this output:

[image: texgyre output]

As the lower case l in the 'Numnito' font has far better readability in chemical formulas than the lower case l in 'TeX Gyre Heros', I would like to know what causes this behaviour under LuaLatex and of course how to solve it.

**Edit**
A closer look at the log file states this:

```
Missing character: There is no δ (U+03B4) in font [Nunito-Regular.otf]:mode=nod
e;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no δ (U+03B4) in font Nunito:mode=node;script=latn;
language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no δ (U+03B4) in font [Nunito-Regular.otf]:mode=nod
e;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no δ (U+03B4) in font [Nunito-Regular.otf]:mode=nod
e;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
] (./chemgreek_lualatex.aux
```

Which is odd, since *delta* is clearly printed in the first default line. When you add the line `\printchemgreekmapping{fontspec}` at the end of the MWE the Greek characters are all printed including *delta*.

Should have known better after reading the log entries - see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually turned out to be a case of *silly me* ....

What causes this behaviour is the lack of a **full** Greek symbol set in the `Nunito` font. `GFS Artemisia` and `TeX Gyre Heros` do have a complete set of Greek characters and hence will print the `'chemdelta` in `\sffamily` mode.

In the preamble the `\selectchemgreekmapping{fontspec}` (or the option `\chemsetup{greek=fontspec}` uses the Greek alphabet provided by `GFS Artemisia`. But when the font family to be used inside `\ch{}` is set to `\sffamily` the mapping of the Greek alphabet is switched to the incomplete set of `Nunito`.

A workaround to maintain the `sans serif` settings in `\ch{}` while using the full Greek character set of `GFS Artemisia` turned out to use the following format: `\ch{\textrm{\chemdelta} ..}`. *Note:* `\mathrm{}` didn't work.

An example MWE to show this workaround:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[body={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[sans-style=upright]{unicode-math} % automatically loads fontspec package
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia}[
    Scale=1.0,
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt]

\setsansfont{Nunito}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]

\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=fontspec,formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
    Using the settings in the preamble: 
    
    \printchemgreekalphabet

    Missing character: \ch{\chemmu-ClO3\mch[]} \ch{\chemalpha-ClO3\mch[]} $\vec{\chemdelta}$

    Correct character: \ch{\textrm{\chemmu}-ClO3\mch[]} \ch{\textrm{\chemalpha}-ClO3\mch[]} $\vec{\textrm{\chemdelta}}$
    
    \bigskip
    \fontspec{Nunito}
    Normal font changed to Nunito font:
    
    \printchemgreekalphabet
    
    Missing character: \ch{\chemmu-ClO3\mch[]} \ch{\chemalpha-ClO3\mch[]} $\vec{\chemdelta}$
    
    Correct character: \ch{\textrm{\chemmu}-ClO3\mch[]} \ch{\textrm{\chemalpha}-ClO3\mch[]} $\vec{\textrm{\chemdelta}}$

\end{document}
```

which gives to following result:

[image: workaround nunito]

Note the differences in the Greek alphabet mapping between the default settings and using `Nunito` as normal font.

**BTW:** a check on other sans serif fonts with a slightly curved lower case l revealed a lot of fonts without a full Greek character set. So be careful which fonts you select ... Hopefully you'll learn from my sillyness ... ;-P